# how do i access additional url parameters after a rewrite rule in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have a rewrite rule in htaccess that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?p/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/ /dir/page.html?&type=$1&state=$2&kw=$3&source=$4&lid=$5 [L]
```

This makes it so when a page like this loads:

www.site.com/pap/type/state/kw/source/lid/

I can access each of the parameters via get in php

```
$_GET["type"]
$_GET["state"]
$_GET["kw"]
$_GET["source"]
$_GET["lid"]
```

The problem is, if a page like this loads:

www.site.com/pap/type/state/kw/source/lid/**?id=blah**

I am not able to access the 'id' paramter using GET.  In other words, this doesn't echo anything:

```
echo $_GET["id"];
```

How would I access the parameter 'id' in this scenario?

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: You should be able to $_GET the parameter after `/` or after `php`. There is no difference, the query string is always present. The problem is not where the string is located, is where the script tha captures it is located. In your example, it has to be at `/lid/` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the flag QSA

```
RewriteRule ^/?p/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/ /dir/page.html?type=$1&state=$2&kw=$3&source=$4&lid=$5 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thank you!  i wished i had asked this earlier knowing now that it was that easy!

Answer (score 1):

Add `[L,QSA]` to the rule.  "Query string append".